# python setup.py install requirement prior to build

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a python package with some cpython components that require py3c headers. The C components are compiled against py3c/py3c.h, which I've added to the setup_requires e.g. like so:

```
setup(name="foo",
      packages=["foo"],
      setup_requires=[
          "py3c",
      ],
      ext_modules=[
          CustomExtension(...),
      ],
      cmdclass={'build_ext': CustomBuild}
     )
```

Where the cmdclass and extension inherit from `build_ext` and `Extension` respectively in order to compile my cpython files. However, regardless of the inclusion of py3c in either `setup_requires` or `install_requires`, py3c is never installed. If I pip install py3c prior to running `setup.py` then the headers are available. Is there a way to get setuptools to install the dependency *before* attempting to build my package?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not that `py3c` is not installed. Most probably it's already there - check out the `.eggs` directory in your project dir, you should find an unpacked egg with `py3c` files. The _real_ problem here is that `easy_install` and thus also `setup_requires` never learned how to properly install the C headers shipped with a python package. So presumably the header files are located under `.eggs/py3c-something.egg/`, and in theory you could point to them when building the extension: `ext_modules=[Extension('spam', sources=['spamlib.c'], include_dirs=['.eggs/py3c-something.egg/'])]`.

Comment: However, `easy_install` will not respect the headers target paths (whereas `pip` does it just fine). So for example, if I include `headers=['foo/bar/baz.h']` in my package, `easy_install` will swallow the target path and install `baz.h` to `mypkg-something.egg/baz.h`. This means that if I have another header where I include `foo/bar/baz.h`, my package will be broken once installed. Looking at [`py3c`'s headers](https://github.com/encukou/py3c/blob/master/include/py3c.h#L30), this is the situation here. Thus, declaring it in `setup_requires` is pointless, unfortunately.

Comment: As for the solution, I think you can extend the `build_ext` command, downloading the headers yourself to some local dir (either from github or the source dist from PyPI) and pointing to that local dir via `include_dirs`.